# Arduino NFC Block Authenication Failed

Tags: authentication, arduino, nfc, mifare, ndef

I pieced together a Arduino Mega 2560 with a SeeedStudio NFC shield 2.0, and used the following libraries:

- https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/PN532
- https://github.com/don/NDEF

I am trying to write some texts into a MiFare Classic card (1024bit, 32 partitions, 64bit ID), but I kept getting the error:

> Error.Block Authentication Failed for 4.

Following is the program that I used:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "PN532_SPI.h"
#include "PN532.h"
#include "NfcAdapter.h"

PN532_SPI interface(SPI, 10);
NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter(interface);

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("NDEF Reader");
  nfc.begin();
}

void loop(void) {
    Serial.println("\nScan a NFC tag\n");
    if (nfc.tagPresent())
    {
        NfcTag tag = nfc.read();
        tag.print();

        Serial.println("Writing to tag...");

        NdefMessage message = NdefMessage();
        message.addTextRecord("Hello, Arduino!");
        nfc.write(message);
    }
    delay(5000);
}
```

Can anyone kindly help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This library only works<sup>1</sup> for MIFARE Classic cards that are preformatted according to NXP's application note on using MIFARE Classic as NDEF tag (see [AN1304](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN1304.pdf) and [AN1305](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN1305.pdf)) **and** that can be written using *key A*<sup>2</sup>.

The error you receive indicates that authentication with key A of the NDEF application (`D3F7D3F7D3F7`) was not possible for sector 1 (typically the first sector of the NDEF application). Thus, it seems that the MF Classic tag was not preformatted (e.g. it could be in transport configuration with all keys set to `FFFFFFFFFFFF`).

Therefore, you need to

1. Create the application directory assigning all sectors to the NDEF application (`E103`). See Annex D in AN1304 for an example.
2. Write all sector trailers of sectors assigned to the NDEF application to set key A to `D3F7D3F7D3F7`, to set the GPB to `40`, to set your application-specific (secret) key B and to set the access conditions to a sensible value. See Annex D in AN1304 for an example.
3. If you set the access conditions to a (not so sensible) value that permits writing using key A, you can use this NDEF library to write your NDEF message to the tag.

---

<sup>1</sup>) In fact this library does not follow AN1304/AN1305 and even *reading* of NDEF messages works only for a *very limited subset* of MIFARE Classic tags used as NDEF tag.

<sup>2</sup>) MIFARE Classic tags used as NDEF tags are typically not writable with the public key A but (if at all) only with the secret key B. Therefore the write functionality of this library is of very limited use.

Comment: Mifare Classic formatting was added to the latest version.